# How to remove overlapping blocks from numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, feature-extraction, overlapping

I'm using `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` function to find feature points in an image. The end goal is to extract square blocks of certain size, with feature points being the centers of those blocks.

However, lots of the feature points are close to each other, so the blocks are overlapping, which is **not** what I want.

This is an example of all feature points (centers):

```
array([[3536., 1419.],
       [2976., 1024.],
       [3504., 1400.],
       [3574., 1505.],
       [3672., 1453.],
       [3671., 1442.],
       [3489., 1429.],
       [3108.,  737.]])
```

Let's say I want to find the first `n` blocks with a `blockRadius = 400` which are **not** overlapping. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need something iterative to do that, as recurrent dropouts like this aren't vectorizable.  Something like this will work, I think

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

c = np.array([[3536., 1419.],
       [2976., 1024.],
       [3504., 1400.],
       [3574., 1505.],
       [3672., 1453.],
       [3671., 1442.],
       [3489., 1429.],
       [3108.,  737.]])

dists = squareform(pdist(c, metric = 'chebyshev'))     # distance matrix, chebyshev here since you seem to want blocks
indices = np.arange(c.shape[0])  # indices that haven't been dropped (all to start)
out = [0]                        # always want the first index
while True:
    try:
        indices = indices[dists[indices[0], indices] > 400] #drop indices that are inside threshhold
        out.append(indices[0])   # add the next index that hasn't been dropped to the output
    except:
        break   # once you run out of indices, you'll get an IndexError and you're done
print(out)
[0, 1]
```

let's try with a whole bunch of points:

```
np.random.seed(42)
c = np.random.rand(10000, 2) * 800
dists = squareform(pdist(c, metric = 'chebyshev'))     # distance matrix, checbyshev here since you seem to want squares
indices = np.arange(c.shape[0])  # indices that haven't been dropped (all to start)
out = [0]                        # always want the first index
while True:
    try:
        indices = indices[dists[indices[0], indices] > 400] #drop indices that are inside threshhold
        out.append(indices[0])   # add the next index that hasn't been dropped to the output
    except:
        break   # once you run out of indices, you'll get an IndexError and you're done
print(out, pdist(c[out], metric = 'chebyshev'))
[0, 2, 6, 17] [635.77582886 590.70015659 472.87353138 541.13920029 647.69071411
 476.84658995]
```

So, 4 points (makes sense since 4 400x400 blocks tile a 800x800 space with 4 tiles), mostly low values (17 << 10000) and distance between kept points is always > 400

Comment: Just want to say that if you have a *lot* of points and my method is starting to bog down /run into memory errors, @mathfux 's method should be significantly faster (although a lot harder to understand without a degree in graph theory).

Comment: I will probably only need max. 8 final centers, so hopefully won't get into those problems.

Answer (score 1):

You could get closer with `scipy.spatial.KDTree` - though it doesn't support querying blocks that consists of distinct amounts of points in blocks. So it can be used in conjunction with another library `python-igraph` that allows to find connected components of close points in a fast manner:

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
import igraph as ig

data = np.array([[3536., 1419.],
       [2976., 1024.],
       [3504., 1400.],
       [3574., 1505.],
       [3672., 1453.],
       [3671., 1442.],
       [3489., 1429.],
       [3108.,  737.]])
edges1 = KDTree(data[:,:1]).query_pairs(r=400)
edges2 = KDTree(data[:,1:]).query_pairs(r=400)
g = ig.Graph(n = len(data), edges=edges1 & edges2)
i = g.clusters()
```

So clusters corresponds to sequences of indices of block points of some kind of internal type `igraph`. There's a quick preview:

```
>>> print(i)
Clustering with 8 elements and 2 clusters
[0] 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
[1] 1, 7
>>> pal = ig.drawing.colors.ClusterColoringPalette(len(i)) #number of colors used
color = pal.get_many(i.membership) #list of color tags
ig.plot(g,  bbox = (200, 100), layout=g.layout('circle'), vertex_label=g.vs.indices, 
        vertex_color = color, vertex_size = 12, vertex_label_size = 8)
```

[image]

Example of usage:

```
>>> [data[n] for n in i] #or list(i)
[array([[3536., 1419.],
        [3504., 1400.],
        [3574., 1505.],
        [3672., 1453.],
        [3671., 1442.],
        [3489., 1429.]]),
 array([[2976., 1024.],
        [3108.,  737.]])]
```

***Remark:*** this method allows to work with pairs of close points instead of `n*n` matrix which is more efficient in memory in some cases.

Comment: Could have sworn `scipy` used to have a `ball_tree` algorithm that could deal with arbitrary metrics at some point.  Only downside of this method is you're stuck with minkowski p-norms, so no chebyshev.